# Was executive meddling the cause of "humans as batteries" in The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

I just ran across this on TVTropes's page "[Human Resources](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanResources)":

> - In The Matrix the robots use humans as batteries! (And recycle the dead into nutrient solution to help feed the living).
>
>   - This would have been Did Not Do the Research if it wasn't that it is all Executive Meddling. The original story had the brains of the humans being used as part of a neural network for additional computing power. But the suits thought that was too hard for people to understand. So instead we get them as batteries, which is Artistic License - Physics.

So:

- Is it true that the original script used humans as part of a neural net?
- And if so, was it changed for the reason given above?

Comment: A pity, because it would have closed that particularly awful plot hole. I don't think "humans as processing power" is more difficult to understand than "humans as electrical power". My grandma wouldn't understand either, of course.

Comment: As so often tvtropes gets it wrong. At no point, any program nor machine confirms the theory of electricity in the films. It is important to note that this is what Morpheus tells us. From how he sums up "history" it is safe to assume they really only know scraps, half of which is probably wrong.

Comment: @AndresF. Hmm..  I wonder if we could explain it away as "Most of the humans in Zion are too dumb to understand, so the techies just told them 'batteries'.".  I mean, we _do_ dumb stuff down in reallife as well...

Comment: @AndresF. the plot hole exist only in the viewers mind. Only humans tell us this is the reason for the fields, not machines. Even Architect says it's ok to kill them. ah, just as bitmask said!

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12244/did-the-machines-use-humans-brains-as-cpus

Comment: The plot hole only exists so that we don't realise we're actually in the Matrix!

Comment: @naxa That would be one way to fix the plothole, to assume the humans are simply mistaken. But I suspect there *is* a plothole and the Wachowski's actually meant the batteries thing in the released movie. (Also, a nitpick: plotholes can only exist in the mind of the viewers, by definition! :) )

Comment: @AndresF. right! about the plothole, the objection that tests the energy explanation seems to ignore a portion of the actual script: `combined with a form of fusion`, which is then indeed unexplained any further. Still, it makes it plausible that enough energy can be drained from human bodies in the movie to make the process worth for the machines.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3822/5930

Comment: I think from the Animatrix, it also mentions batteries. The humans blocked out the sun (operation dark storm) to cut off power to the robots. The humans were used as an alternative source of energy. I'm going from memory though, so please double check this. Also the animatrix was released after the matrix.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, this is true, though its not clear how hard the Wachowskis fought to keep their original idea.

The only "official statement" I know of is an off-hand comment from one of the Wachowskis on the DVD commentary for one of the director's cuts (I forget which but I *think* its on *the Ultimate Matrix Collection*.) They discussed the whole setup for the Matrix and mentions that they "originally had a different idea" before dismissing the question as irrelevant to the story. (e.g. it doesn't matter to *them* why the machines did what they did, as its just a plot device to get the story started.)

More details about what that original plan was come from some written material based on early pre-release information from the movie. Specifically, Neil Gaiman's short story "Goliath" is set in the Matrix universe and includes this alternate view. I have also heard that the "novelization" of the Matrix included this idea but there's no such novel that I know of; its possible that a novelized version of an early script exists (there's a published version of the shooting script for sale but that includes the story as filmed.)

Comment: 96 draft is like the movie already http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/matrix_96_draft.txt

Comment: If "humans as processors" is just a plot device to Mr. Wachowsky, then, seriously, shame on him.

Comment: Why? He's a writer. Every word he writes is "just a plot device". That's the point of writing fiction - to produce a plot.

Comment: Yes, and bonus points to those writers who create credible plot devices and explore their proper value to the story.

Comment: Argh. I'd really like that as an official statement somewhere.

Comment: I'd like to see the source of that off-hand comment--the Wachowskis didn't do any commentary tracks, was it a different special feature on a DVD/blu-ray? [This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/matrix/comments/q2xefs/batteries_not_processors/) has some evidence against the idea that the Wachowskis originally intended for humans to be processors--it shows the idea of humans as batteries was present in the earliest script drafts going back to 1996, and a quote from Gaiman indicating that his story's use of the processor idea was his own invention, not something from the script he read.

Answer (score -3):

Lana Wachowski answered this question in an interview (I believe it was with a French radio DJ, although the interview was done in English).

She was asked specifically about this change and corroborated that a producer requested the change from the original script (in which the humans brains were tapped for their computational power) to the humans being used as an energy source.

Further, she was asked why they [the Wachowskis] didn't fight the change and her answer was that it just wasn't that important to them "it was only a plot device".

Comment: You've made this claim about an interview a few times (last time, I think you said it was on the DVD). Can you give more information about where, specifically, we can listen to said interview?