# Comparison of the programs of the Matrix and the machines of the real world?

Tags: the-matrix

What was the position of a program that resided in the matrix when compared to a machine in the real world? Were the machines of the real world superior? If yes, why? If no, then what was their position like? Did the machines even have notions like that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'position'? Do you mean physical position? Or 'role'? Are you making a distinction between the programmes running the agents and the programmes running the machines? If so, excellent question!

Comment: I'd guess it's asking about hierarchies.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/what-kind-of-a-political-hierarchy-do-the-machines-in-the-matrix-have

Comment: I am not talking about "hierarchies" I just want to know if the ones in matrix felt a bit different from the ones outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each program in the Matrix was an [AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence).  They were all designed to perform a task and to be intelligent enough to learn and self correct in their daily activities.  Each AI in the Matrix was distinct, and, the ones that had feelings for sure like the Merovingian by virtue of being a unique intelligent entity definitely must have felt much different from any of the machines on the outside.

The ones that may or may not have feelings that a human could relate to, like The Architect, don't "feel" different per se, but their modes of operation are unique as these are intelligences with personalities that can reason we're discussing.

Other than the Deus Ex Machina, it's unclear from canonical sources I've seen if the machines outside of the Matrix were even self aware.  I don't think that the ones we saw in the film were for the most part, or they would have done something other than blindly charge the Nebuchunezzer and get EMP'd.

It follows that an intelligent machine would have either encountered hostility like this before and planned an attack whereby only half of the aggressors were in range of the EMP and the rest could then finish off the enemy. (They'd know from previous encounters that the EMP needs time before it can be fired again.)  It also follows that an intelligent machine with understanding of 3 dimensions and flight wouldn't have let Neo's ship go over them. :P

Comment: while you were right about some parts, I think the sentinels are what you were referring to when talking about the machines in the real world. Those were machines that were built with purpose and were not "AI" however, this does not mean that the machine city was devoid of any AI except for the Deus Ex Machina. You see, Agent Smith tells Morpheous that he was tired the prison(matrix) and wanted to be free of it. So, that clearly suggested that there were other machines on the "outside" that were sentient.

Comment: I never said that the machine city was devoid of AI except the Deus Ex Machina.  I said that it's unclear canonically.  I don't know of any example of machines that showed clear signs of intelligence outside the matrix.  You're assuming you know that Smith wanted to get outside to the real world when he said that, I think it's just as likely that meant he wanted to get into the mainframe that ran Machine City and ruin it, and that's why the Deus Ex Machina needed Neo.  It might even be more likely that's what Smith was intending, as that's what he did.

Comment: Ruining the machine main frame was never Agent Smith's agenda. When Neo destroyed him initially, he know that he should be deleted but he refused and survived for a new single goal to be achieved, and that is to destroy Neo which he completes and that is why his will to survive is gone. He called the matrix a prison and wanted to go outside. I do not believe he had anything more in his mind before being unplugged.

Comment: Smith clearly says he wants to control all of the Matrix and Machine City,  "I want what you want: ...everything."  This is a clear indication that he had more designs than simply defeating Neo.  I'm not sure where you've gotten the idea that A) his goal was only to kill neo, or B) That his will to survive was gone.  In fact, his will to survive was clearly still strong as he yelled in frustration when Neo conquored him. Further, Smith never "chose" anything, he is also quoted as saying "We're not here because we're free, we're here because we're *not* free," indicating he has no choices.

Comment: Finally, The Oracle herself said that Smith would "seep into the real world and the machine world and consume BOTH", indicating that he had bigger designs than simply Neo.  If my answer is insufficient please tell me exactly why so that I can provide you with that you're looking for.  Otherwise, perhaps you could accept the answer?