# Who originally programmed "The Matrix"?

Tags: the-matrix, computers

I know it says the "The Architect" is the architect... but I guess I am asking, as a software developer myself, how could one person program the whole matrix himself? It would take many lifetimes to develop a program that extravagant by yourself. Did he have a team of developers? Was it a project that was stolen by the government? Did AI help out? Any thoughts?

Comment: The Architect isn't a person, he is an artificial intelligence.

Comment: @JackBNimble: Why can't he be both? A [person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person) must not necessarily be human.

Comment: @bitmask bits and bytes do not a person make.

Comment: @JackBNimble [Depends on your point of view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_Data)...  (Yeah yeah, wrong universe.  Meh.)

Comment: @JackBNimble he doesn't have to be a person to create a computer software. One of the goals of creating an AI is that it will be able to replicate the human thought process, including the ability to create new systems by learning from existing systems.

Comment: I wrote a comment about this question or I wrote a question; that the 'individuals' within the matrix were 'partly' programming the Matrix in it's 'day to day' interactions so the Architect wrote the 'initial' conditions of the Matrix , all the basic 'rules' of any 'physical interactions' etc.; the Architect couldn't have written algorithms to 'cover' all possible human interactions and activities , the people's minds themselves would be 'programming' for this. I wrote something like this and it has disappeared or was censored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who created The Matrix? **The machines**.

There was no team of programmers. The artificial intelligence that man created spiraled out of control and programmed its own virtual reality construct.

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Matrix,-The.html) (This is from a lightly older version, so dialog is a little off, but the facts are still the same. I've also snipped out some extraneous dialog/action/scenery descriptions)

> **MORPHEUS**
>
> It started early in the twenty-
>   first century, with the birth of
>   artificial intelligence, a
>   singular consciousness that
>   spawned an entire race of
>   machines.
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> At first all they wanted was to be
>   treated as equals, entitled to the
>   same human inalienable rights.
>   Whatever they were given, it was
>   not enough.
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> We don't know who struck first.
>   Us or them.  But sometime at the
>   end of the twenty-first century
>   the battle was joined.
>
> (massive snip)
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> We are, as an energy source,
>   easily renewable and completely
>   recyclable, the dead liquified and
>   fed intravenously to the living.
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> All they needed to control this
>   new battery was something to
>   occupy our mind.
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> And so they built a prison out of
>   our past, wired it to our brains
>   and turned us into slaves.
>
> **NEO**
>
> No!  I don't believe it!  It's not
>   possible!
>
> **MORPHEUS**
>
> I didn't say that it would be
>   easy, Neo.  I just said that it
>   would be the truth.

Agent Smith later backs this up when he talks to the captive Morpheus. In this situation, it's fairly safe to assume that "we" refers to "the machines" as a whole, and not "we agents".

> **AGENT SMITH**
>
> Did you know that the first Matrix
>   was designed to be a perfect human
>   world?  Where none suffered, where
>   everyone would be happy.  It was a
>   disaster.  No one would accept the
>   program.  Entire crops were lost.
>
> **AGENT SMITH**
>
> Some believed we lacked the
>   programming language to describe
>   your perfect world.  But I believe
>   that, as a species, human beings
>   define their reality through
>   suffering and misery.
>
> **AGENT SMITH**
>
> The perfect world was a dream that
>   your primitive cerebrum kept
>   trying to wake up from.  Which is
>   why the Matrix was re-designed to
>   this:  the peak of your
>   civilization.

Comment: We know Morpheus to be an unreliable narrator. What he believes is part of the control system created by the machines, so his word alone ought not to be take at face value.

Comment: Fair, but you also pointed out the quote from Agent Smith which I had forgotten about. That backs up his story, IMO.

Comment: Well, it's just a bonus, really. [It has been pointed out before](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12369/2565), that all information Zion has about how the matrix came into existence might be false and a way of guilting the humans.

Comment: @bitmask Exactly so. Morpheus doesn't even know that Zion has been repeatedly destroyed or even if the Zionians are still inside the matrix. His knowledge is incredibly flawed.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [phantom42](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48332/2565)'s answer, [the Animatrix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0328832/) provides additional detail.

In summary, humans attacked the machine city out of irrational fear but were nowhere close to being a match for the massive (defensive) army the machines had. The humans, however — or so the premise — clouded the sky in order to remove the main energy source of the machines (this is shown in detail).

After being victorious, the machines worked out a "peace treaty", without the humans having *any* say. In a sense, the humans were forced to pay reparations.

[image: post-war]

> Machine: Your flesh is a relic, a mere vessel. Hand over your flesh and a new world awaits you. We demand it!

To implement these reparations, the machines physically bound the humans in order to harness their biochemical energy:

[image: expermentation]

However, as Mr. Smith [points out](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Matrix,-The.html), they had to go through several iterations of the Matrix, until they worked out something that was suitable for humans:

> Did you know that the first Matrix            was designed to be a perfect human          world?  Where none suffered, where
>             everyone would be happy.  It was a          disaster.  No one would
>   accept the            program.  Entire crops were lost.
>
> Some believed we lacked the           programming language to describe            your perfect world.  But I believe          that, as
>   a species, human beings           define their reality through            suffering
>   and misery.
>
> The perfect world was a dream that            your primitive cerebrum kept            trying to wake up from.  Which is           why
>   the Matrix was re-designed to             this:  the peak of your
>             civilization.

So, all in all this means that **the Matrix was specifically designed by the machines *after* the human-machine war**. However, this information [might be unreliable](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12369/2565) as we don't know for sure where the "Zion Archives" originate from (The Animatrix never explains their origin, they're just there), and Mr. Smith, although not a liar, evidently lacks information that other machines have and is being lied to by his superiors, so what he thinks he knows might actually be a fabrication. We are never told.

Answer (score 2):

### The Machines programmed the Matrix after the end of the first Human/Machine war.

There are several canon (Wachowski Brothers) sources for the creation of the Matrix.

Within the film series, there is a [discussion between Smith and Morpheus](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Matrix,-The.html) about the creation of the very first Matrix;

> AGENT SMITH : Did you know that the first Matrix was designed to be a
> perfect human world?  Where none suffered, where everyone would be
> happy.  It was a disaster.  No one would accept the program.  Entire
> crops were lost.
>
> AGENT SMITH : Some believed we lacked the programming language to
> describe your perfect world.  But I believe that, as a species, human
> beings define their reality through suffering and misery.
>
> AGENT SMITH : The perfect world was a dream that your primitive
> cerebrum kept trying to wake up from.  Which is why the Matrix was
> re-designed to this:  the peak of your civilization.

When Neo meets the Architect (e.g a projection of the Matrix programming) in "Matrix Revolutions", he [specifically tells him](http://www.horrorlair.com/movies/scripts/matrixreloaded.pdf) that *he* created the Matrix;

> Neo : Who are you?
>
> Architect : I am the Architect, I created the
> Matrix. I've been waiting for you"

As if that wasn't enough, in the Animatrix story "[The Second Renaissance: Part II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Animatrix#.22The_Second_Renaissance_Part_II.22)" we actually **see** the first crude Matrix 'power plant' being created by the machines as well as humans being experimented on to try to alter their perceptions, clearly a precursor to the Matrix inhabited by Neo and his comrades.

[image: Animatrix - First Matrix]

Answer (score -1):

In simplest terms, the Matrix was created by the machine (The Architect) as a place to put these squirmy, smarmy durcell batteries they called man kind.   It was never programmed by man, but was erected by the machine itself.

aaand... someone beat me to the punch with this answer... LOL

Comment: The Matrix was 'initialized' by the Architect but it's 'daily' actions were partly being 'run' by the participating Humans and how they interacted with and cause changes 'within' the Matrix.